# iPhone application name on iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, info.plist

Is there any way to set the display name of the application which is shown on [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) and on [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) different? The name that I wrote to "Display bundle name" in `info.plist` is shown both on iTunes and iPhone, is there any way to separate them?

My second question is: how can I change the genre of my application? Now it's "Unknown Genre".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name that is displayed on the iPhone beneath the icon is set in the "Product Name" build setting for your apps target. You can set this to whatever you feel appropriate.

Then whatever name you entered as the App Name in iTunes Connect is shown in iTunes and the App Store.

Apps don't normally have a genre. Apps are separated into Categories, of which you should have been able to pick 2 (primary and secondary) during your submission through iTunes Connect.

You should be able to update these category choices by logging into iTunes Connect and editing your app.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it is true what you wrote. We once got an app rejected because of this:

XXXX has been rejected because of a naming inconsistency. The name entered into iTunes Connect must match the name of the application installed. The name entered into iTunes Connect is XXXX while the name of the application installed is YYYY. In order for your application to be reconsidered for the App Store, please resolve this issue and upload your new binary to iTunes Connect.

The way to change the displayed application name in Xcode is to change the "Product Name" entry in your Target's Build Info pane. To do this:

1. Select your Target on the left side under Groups & Files
2. Select File > Get Info
3. Select the Build tab
4. From the Configurations popup, select All Configurations
5. In the search box, type in "product name"
6. Double-click the entry field and type in the new name of your product, and select OK.
7. In your Info.plist, change your Bundle Display Name and your Bundle Name appropriately.
8. Do a clean build (Build > Clean all targets; Build > Build)

Once these steps are completed you should see a newly built binary under the Products folder. Do not change your Bundle Identifier. This is used to uniquely identify your application in the App Store. Changing it would prevent users from upgrading, and effectively introduce a new application rather than an update.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong but this is possible that app has two names(one for iTune conect and other for iPhone).
I have checked an app "iTune connect names is "Remember the milk" and name in iPhone is "RTM" ".

Answer (score 0):

There is clause in AppStore Review Guidelines.

Please review link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines

**App May Reject due to:**

```
3.4  App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion
```