# iPhone app displaying a different name

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone application name on iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979689/iphone-application-name-on-itunes)

My app name is really big and on the home screen under the icon, I get "dots" in between the beginning and end of the name. Is it possible to display a different (short version) of the name on home screen but keep the larger name for iTunes?

Comment: [This][1] is the answer to your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979689/iphone-application-name-on-itunes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/8962-change-iphone-app-name.html), you can change your app name in info.plist (Bundle Display Name) without affecting your App's iTunes name. Also see this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979689/iphone-application-name-on-itunes).